# What is "ELF load command"?

Tags: elf

I'm trying to create an ELF executable myself (i.e. writing bytes out to a file), and running

```
ld.2.23.so ./o
```

prints error

```
./o: error while loading shared libraries: ./o: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned
```

I've checked the ELF specification, and there is no reference to a Load command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found the answer. Had to look into source code.

dl-load.c has this:

```
case PT_LOAD:
      /* A load command tells us to map in part of the file.
         We record the load commands and process them all later.  */
...
      if ...
        {
          errstring
        = N_("ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned");
```

IMHO, weird error message: PT_LOAD is never referred to as a command in the specs; the address/offset alignment requirements are somewhat obscured in the specs; in fact, the specs dont even have the words 'load command'.

And the offending segment identifier or sorts would be helpful, too. But, then again, having this message is better than just a sigfault

Comment: It is normal since the LD implementation has nothing to do with the elf specification which is an open source specification

Comment: ld is just telling that the alignment for this segment wasn't correct

Comment: You're exactly right, LD is an implementation of the specification. Thus, I'd expect it to adhere to the specification, including in the terms it uses, rather than invent it's own terms for what has been termed in the specification

Comment: Well actually this is an error thrown by ld. It has nothing to do with the elf spec. ld isn't an implementation of the elf spec it just links the elf object files in final executable. The job of ld isn't to find all mistakes you made while implementing the elf spec which is well documented. It's job is only to link well formated code. If you make a mistake ld is limited in telling you what's wrong simply because developpers cannot think of everything wrong that can happen while linking. Some general exceptions can happen which don't have proper error messages.

Comment: There cannot be "commands" in the elf spec since elf is a file format.

Comment: @user123 "because the developers cannot hink of everything wrong that can happen" - imho that's exactly what those developer should've done; and they've had about 20yrs to do that. I just hope these developer aren't on to developing space crafts or unmanned cars.